# Android Horizontal Image Scroll

Tags: android, design-patterns, user-interface, foursquare

I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar to what Airbnb, FourSquare and Grand St have done. I want to have a collection of a few images and display one image at a time on a portion of the activity and be able to swipe left and right to see the next picture. They usually have an indicator on the bottom portion over the picture to show where you are in the list of images. Airbnb has it all over the place, Foursquare has it on details page for an establishment, Grand St has it when you open up the details on a product. I thought I saw something on this on an Android Design in Action video but can't find it. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the source code of a gallery application in which they have animations of sliding the images left and right. 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/Gallery.java

Comment: Gallery widget has been deprecated and it says to use  HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager, is that what these apps use? I don't see anything on how to add some sort of indicator overlay to the image to show which image your are on and how many are left in either direction.

Comment: Hm well i guess i might have hunted an old gallary file . I am away from pc as ofnow, but i will provide u a new link of CyanogenMod 10 gallary source from github. Try to Google it till then